# JPA/Hibernate fetch

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes with OneToMany one-directional relationship.

```
 class A {
    @Column(name = "a_id")
    Integer id;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private List<B> listOfB;
    //getters and setters
}

class B {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    @Column("a_id")
    Integer aId;
    //getters and setters
}
```

In database I already have saved instance of B.
I need to do:

```
a.listOfB.add(b);
save(a);
```

In object `b` in database I have id and name, but fk is null. I need to update fk, but before it I need to fetch object `b`;
How can I do it?

Only by writing custom method, or Hibernate/JPA have its own method to fetch objects?

Comment: *In database I already have saved instance of B* - not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is not very common. Common way to have `@JoinColumn` in `B` and `mappedBy = "a"` in `A`. And you can specify `cascade`. In the simplest case `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.

```
    class A {
        @Column(name = "a_id")
        Integer id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<B>;

        public void addB(B b) {
           b.setA(this); 
           listOfB.add(b);
        }
    }

    class B {
        Integer id;
        String name;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
        private A a;
    }
```

To solve your issue

```
save(a);
b.setA(a);
saveOrUpdate(b);
```

And `cascade` will help you to do the same by almost your way with a help of `addB()` method

```
a.addB(b);
save(a);
```